# how to get the pid_t of the running dock.app in max os X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, dock

More or less everything is in the title, I am looking for a way to get from a cocoa application, pid_t of the running dock.app.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean? sorry Englsh is not my native language.

Comment: @AP he means "Why do you need to know?". Usually you need the `pid_t` of an app in order to manipulate the process, and manipulating the Dock is usually not a Good Idea™.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running Mac OS X 10.6, then you can give a try to the `runningApplications` method of `NSWorkspace`:

```
NSArray *appList = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
```

It will return an array of [NSRunningApplication](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Look up for `Dock.app` and use the `processIdentifier` property.

You can also take a look at the [AppList](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/AppList/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008859) sample application.

Comment: +1, except that it'd be smarter to look for an `NSRunningApplication` with the `com.apple.dock` bundle identifier, rather than `Dock.app`